# Add permission for scripts only to run in Travis CI and not locally

Tags: javascript, npm, permissions, travis-ci, continuous-deployment

I want to lock down some scripts in my `.travis.yml` to only be ran in the Travis CI build environment and prevent them from being ran locally on a users machine.

where the config in the `.travis.yml` would look something like this:

```
# .travis.yml

script:
  - npm run deploy-from-travis-only
```

If there is a better approach, I'm also open to other ideas.

Answer (score 4):

If you merely intend to prevent other users from accidentally run these scripts, you can set some guard in these scripts to check if travis [default env variables](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/environment-variables/#default-environment-variables) are set accordingly, e.g.

```
// deploy-from-travis-only.js

function main() {
  // the guard:
  if (!process.env.CI || !process.env.TRAVIS) return;
  // if pass the guard, then execute normally
  ...
}

main();
```